# Present modal UIViewController over UISplitViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I've written the code below to present a modal `UIViewController` on top of a `UISplitViewController` from `AppDelegate`. However, it keeps throwing `Application tried to present modally an active controller <UISplitViewController: 0x138023800>.`.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {
    NSLog(@"%@", shortcutItem.type);
    if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.myapp.show-me"]){
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UISplitViewController *tc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplitViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = tc;
        UINavigationController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Navigation"];
        UIViewController *detailViewController = [ivc.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        detailViewController.restaurant = @"1";
        [tc presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else if([shortcutItem.type isEqualToString:@"com.myapp.see-all"]){
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UISplitViewController *tc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SplitViewController"];
        self.window.rootViewController = tc;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong with `com.myapp.show-me`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I only needed to present the `UINavigationController` instead of the `UIViewController`.

```
[tc presentViewController:ivc animated:YES completion:nil];
```